# An interesting property of curves $V:$ $x^3$ + $y^3$ = A$z^3$

Tags: number-theory

Let $V$ be the elliptic curve V: $x^3$+ $y^3$ = A$z^3$ where  A > 2 is cube free natural number. A conjugate quadratic point of $V$ is one of the form $(a + b\sqrt d, a - b\sqrt d, c)$ (note that all quadratic point $(x, y, z)$ of $V$ can be reduced to have $z$ rational integer multiplying by the conjugate of $z$). I have found the result which follows and I am interested in knowing the opinion and remarks or possible objections of readers and mainly I expect for another proof.

**Prove that $V(\mathbb Q)$ has no rational points distinct of $(1, -1, 0)$ if and only if all the quadratic points of $V$ are conjugates.**

EXAMPLE.- This is true even with $x^3$ + $y^3$ = 2$z^3$ in which the only rational points are $(1, 1, 1)$ and $(1, -1, 0)$. One has here, with $A = 2$, the point $(4 +2\sqrt{-11}, -1 + \sqrt{-11}, -6)$ which is not conjugate because of the rational point $(1, 1, 1)$.

Comment: Care to share your existing proof?

Comment: @Justaskin Not at all. I want to say thanks to the reader who has edited the "good" Q (he have erased his name).

Comment: I solved a similar equation. Used this approach.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114766/diophantine-equation-3-rd-degree  Can anyone suggest better?

Comment: @individ You can go from your equation to a V here with A = ab but the solutions (X, Y, Z) here will be polynomials of the 9 degree in your original solutions (x, y, z). Besides here is a question about quadratic points.

Comment: @individ The A  for come from your equation to a V here is a$b^2$ and not the ab above. All the other is true. Anyway, come to the curves V is not a good affair to solve your equation.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone wishing to see the proof can see it on this link (it's in Spanish). There are preliminary details starting on page 108 but the proof is reduced to pages 112-113

http://revistas.pucp.edu.pe/index.php/promathematica/article/download/8186/8482.